# When using pseudo random numbers to estimate the value of pi I am getting a value around 2.44. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, random

I am determining the value of PI based on ernesto cesaros therom. I am using the default random method in java. I set the seed value as an input which will determine how many pairs of random numbers it will generate. I am always getting a value around 2.4494

```
    import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Projectone {
public static int count, sum = 0;
public static int a, b, gd;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Enter seed number
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter seed value: ");
    int seed = kb.nextInt();
    // Generate pairs of random numbers based on the seed number
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i <= seed; i++) {
        count++;
        int a = rand.nextInt();
        int b = rand.nextInt();
        // Eliminating all negative numbers
        if (a < 0) {
            a *= -1;
        }
        if (b < 0) {
            b *= -1;
        }
        // Entering random numbers into gcd
        gd = gcd(a, b);
        System.out.println("a = " + a + " b= " + b);
        // breaks loop if gcd is =1 and adds the gcd
        if (gd == 1)
            break;

        for (int j = 0; j <= seed; j++) {
            sum += gd;

        }

    }
    System.out.println("this is the count " + count);
    if (sum == 0) {
        sum = 1;
    }
    System.out.println("The sumation of the gcd's = " + sum);
    //pluging in the values to the ceseros formula
    float pi=(float) Math.sqrt(6.f*count/sum);
    System.out.println("the ans is: "+pi);
}
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
        int c = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = c;
    }
    return a + b;
     }
  }
```

Also I was wondering how to generate true random numbers

Comment: When you mention `seed` I automatically thought of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)

Comment: You will find the algorithm for the calculation here http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2009/09/python-calculating-pi-using-random-numbers/ ... it is in Python, but its very clear

Comment: @Kh.Taheri that's a completely different algorithm...

Comment: where is the source (the algorithm) that you are following?

Comment: for the theorem I am calculating pi =(sqrt(6*n))/p
n= number of pairs of x and y. i this case it is equal to the seed value
p=gcd sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually **code** what the theorem states, which is that

> the probability that two random numbers are coprimes is 6 / pi^2

Which is 0.60792710185.

or stated otherwise

> pi = sqrt(6 / found_probability)

and thus

> pi = sqrt(6 * tries / found_coprimes)

Obviously, you'll need to repeat the test a serious number of times to obtain a reasonable approximation of pi.

Now, in your code:

- you **stop** iterating the first time you encounter a gcd of 1 (ie, a coprime). Right there and then it's game over.
- and then you start adding gcd, for a reason that's completely unclear to me. the obtained gcd values are completely irrelevant for the result.

Consider this code:

```
private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
        int c = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = c;
    }
    return a + b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();

    int iv = 1000000;
    int coprime = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < iv; i++) {
        int int1 = Math.abs(random.nextInt());
        int int2 = Math.abs(random.nextInt());
        if (gcd(int1, int2) == 1) {
            coprime++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(6.0 * iv / coprime));
}
```

which gives results like

3.1425778292704583

---

Regarding your second question, the standard "random" number generators are actually pseudo random generators. True random numbers are very hard to get, read [True random generation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381037/true-random-generation-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

The probability that your numbers are relatively prime is

```
P=number of pairs that are relatively prime/total number of pairs
```

Based on this you can reformulate your algorithm:

```
pi=Math.sqrt(6/P)
```

Plus your loops should not reach i<=upperLimit if you are starting from 0; i < upperLimit