# Random numbers in Java

Tags: java, android, random

How to draw a number from 0 to 4 in Java (Android)?
How to use the Random function?

Answer (score 9):

The follwing will do what you need.

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomInt = r.nextInt(5);
```

If you do this in a loop, make sure you initialize the `Random` outside of the loop.

```
Random r = new Random();
for(int i = 0;i < someThing; i++) {
    System.out.println(r.nextInt(5));
}
```

See the documentation for the `Random` class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 3):

Please Pay Attantion - Calling each time the code:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Will probably return you the same numbers (i guess few of you have noticed that phanamona).

I guess it connected somehow to the Java problem with random numbers:
[Java: Can (new Random()).nextInt(5) always return the same number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045013/java-can-new-random-nextint5-always-return-the-same-number)
and: [Java random always returns the same number when I set the seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533191/java-random-always-returns-the-same-number-when-i-set-the-seed)

Anyway my solution is to add a static variable to my class:

```
static Random sRandomGen = new Random();
```

and call the nextInt from the relevant method when i need the random number. Thatway i recieve an equal dividing between results.

```
int rnd = sRandomGen.nextInt(numofmatches - 1);
```

This solution works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to be careful of is that you shouldn't create a new Random object every time you want a new number. This line should be executed once when the application starts:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Then this should be called each time you want a new random number:

```
int x = r.nextInt(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(""+(int) (Math.random()*5.0));
```

If you only need to generate a single random number, I believe it's slightly cheaper to use the Math.random() than to make an object.

Note: to generate any random integer from 0 to n, (0 inclusive, n exclusive), just use:

```
(int) (Math.random()*n);
```

To generate any random integer from m to m+n, (m inclusive, m+n exclusive), just use:

```
m + (int) (Math.random()*n);
```

Comment: Constructing an instance of Random is not necessary more expensive than your way

Comment: Ognian is correct, and to clarify, the first call to Math.random() actually creates a new java.util.Random object which will be used by all subsequent calls to Math.random().