# Increasing Probability for generating specific random numbers

Tags: java

I want to generate random numbers . Now, I want to generate a new set of random numbers in a way that that increases the probability of returning the numbers that were generated earlier.What is the best way of achieving this ?

Comment: If you use the same seed for the random number generator it will generate the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: This may be the answer...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458383/java-random-numbers-using-a-seed

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if predefined functions exist or not, but I have something in mind that you can try.

1. Make an ArrayList of the numbers. (eg. if you want to generate from
   0to30, then make an ArrayList of Integers from 0 to 30).
2. Shuffle the ArrayList(`Collections.shuffle()`)
3. Pick the first 2 numbers.
4. Then, just add those 2 numbers into the ArrayList as many times as you want the probablity to shift towards them.
5. Shuffle again and pick

Answer (score 0):

You can store that values on array.
And you can have a random condition also for having a new pair of number or pick randomly on your array.