# What exactly does the parameter seed in MLContext do?

Tags: c#, random, ml.net

I am working in a ML project, I have never used C# and specially the ML.NET for this purpose. My question is: What does this line of code mean? I am creating an instance of the class MLContext, but I do not understand the parameters. Seed generates a random number but, what does `:0` mean?

```
var mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
```

Comment: That's a [named parameter in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), this would be the same: `var mlContext = new MLContext(0);`

Comment: We use `seed` to *reproduce* random values generated: if you run the routine again, the result will be the *same*, since random values will be same. If you omit `seed`, the `seed` will be taken from system timer and random values will be different for different runs. `seed` is very useful when *debugging*, *testing* to guarantee same randoms for different executions

Comment: Although this is about Java Random generator, the principle of a seed is the same. Does this answer your question? [Java random numbers using a seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458383/java-random-numbers-using-a-seed)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you very much, now I understand how it works and why I need to use this in my code

Comment: @derpirscher yes that is thesame principle, now I have fully understand, thank you very much