# Java Random Number Generator using a Seed

Tags: java, random, seed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java random always returns the same number when I set the seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533191/java-random-always-returns-the-same-number-when-i-set-the-seed)
>   [Java Random Numbers Using a Seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458383/java-random-numbers-using-a-seed)

**Hi, 
This is my code. I am trying to generate 2 random numbers simultaneously using a seed i.e. 15416640. The numbers that are getting generate are not really random.**

```
Random radiusGenerator = new Random(15416640);

Random angleGenerator = new Random(15416640);

try
{
    for(int i=1; i<=sequenceNumber; i++)
    {
        double radius =  (0.5 - (0.5 * Math.sqrt(1-radiusGenerator.nextDouble())));
        double angle = angleGenerator.nextDouble();
        angle = angle*(Math.PI*2);

        System.out.print(radius+"      "+ angle +"\n");
     }
```

**Please Help...Thanks!**

Comment: Use one Random object, and generate everything you want.

Comment: and the above duplicate is posted by same user yesterday !!!

Comment: @mtk well seen. OP, tell us if something wasn't clear or still isn't clear, so that you don't have to ask again.

Answer (score 1):

That's totally normal and a feature : in a [Pseudo Random Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), the seed defines the sequence of numbers that will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Use one `Random` object, and generate everything you want. Since you initialize 2 `Random` object with the same seed, they will generate the same number if you call with the same method.

Comment: even if i am using one generator....the numbers are not properly random

Comment: @RahulBhatia: Use the seed = current time in milliseconds from Epoch.

Comment: @RahulBhatia Please read the answers given to your previous question : both explanation and solution were provided