# j2me random doesn`t work

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java random always returns the same number when I set the seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533191/java-random-always-returns-the-same-number-when-i-set-the-seed)

In my game there is 4 monsters which are moving to the same random generated coordinates. It means random is not working.

```
 public void run() {
    while (true) {

                    // paints all Sprites, and graphics
        updateScreen(getGraphics());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}


private void updateScreen(Graphics g) {

     loops through all monsters and moves them a bit
     for (int gi = 0; gi < bottX.length; gi++) {

      bot(gi); // moves a  specified monster or gets new coordinates
     }

}

private void bot(int c) {

// some stuff to move a monster



 // if a monster is in desired place, generate new coordinates

    if(isInPlace()){
       // g]randomly generates new coordinates X and Y
        botX(c);
    botY(c);

    }


 }



public void botX(int c) {

           // monsters walking coordinates are between 30 px from the spawn zone.
    Random r1 = new Random();
    int s = r1.nextInt(3);
    // number 0 - left 1 - right 2 - don`t go in X axis
            // monster spawn coordinate
    int botox = spawnnX[c];
    int einamx;


    if (s == 0) {

        einamx = r1.nextInt(30) + (botox - 30); 
                    // [botox-30; botox)
    } else if (s == 1) {
        einamx = r1.nextInt(29) + (botox + 1); // (botoX+1 botoX+30]
    } else {
        einamx = botox;
    }



            // sets to where the monster should go
    einammX[c] = einamx;
    return;




          }
```

So in this game is 4 monsters which spawn coordinates are equals and you can only see 1 monter because they are moving the same. BTW if I set spawn coordinates different i can see 4 monsters which are moving the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create one Random and reuse that instead of creating a new every time (if you have multiple threads create one per thread).

Comment: Yes it works when I created only one Random object

Answer (score 1):

I suspect strongly that `Random` *does* work! From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the
>   same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and
>   return identical sequences of numbers.

and

> Two Random objects created within the same millisecond will have the
>   same sequence of random numbers.

So I suspect you're creating multiple `Random` instances with the same seed, and so you're getting the same sequence of random numbers each time.

Comment: Yes it is true but i dont want to stop the script by putting in Thread.sleep

Comment: You don't need to. Just create one instance and call nextInt() on that each time

Answer (score 1):

With older versions of Java 1.4.2 and previous, and possibly the version you are using, the Random was seeded with the `System.currentTimeMillis()`  This meant if you creating multiple Random to within the resolution of this call, between 1 and 16 ms, you would get the same seed.

A simple work around is to create one `Random` and re-use it. This is more efficient and ensures each call will give a random value.

Java 5.0 fixed this by using System.nanoTime() and an AtomicLong counetr to ensure the seed is different each time.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a seed issue. Use the `new Random(seed)` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29).

Perhaps you could call it with something like

```
new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

although if you call this multiple times within the same millisecond you will have the same issue. I dont think you will need to call multiple times though. Just reuse the object.