# value zero generated numerously using random function()

Tags: java, android

```
/*This is my function code*/
Random random = new Random();
int randomInt = random.nextInt()%200;

String imgName = "img" + randomInt;

int ImageId = getResources().getIndentifier(imgName,"drawabale",getPackageName());
myImage.setImageResourse(ImageId);
```

Previously in my drawable folder there are 
    200 images already inserted using img1,img2.....img199 
like nomenclature...
    every time I call random function mention below to generated one 
    random number and form a string name starting from 
    "img" and some number. But most of time only 0 is generated by random function and id set to 
    image is display 0th image constantly..at some point it successfully display other images but most of time it generated zero value continuosly.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Maybe check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533191/java-random-always-returns-the-same-number-when-i-set-the-seed
I think you need to share the Random() instance across the whole class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate Random number with specific Range

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomInt = r.nextInt(maxVal - minVal) + minVal
```

For your example

```
 int randomInt = r.nextInt(200 - 1) + 1
```

Will generate number between 1 to 199.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein not understood. As per [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) r.nextInt(index) will generate value 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive). so for index 199 it will generate between 0 to 198 and +1 means 1 to 199. isn't it true?

Comment: Right, overlooked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A random number generated by `nextInt` should be a multiple of `200` at random, i.e. one every `200` or so. This test suggests this is happening correctly:

```
public void test() {
    Random random = new Random();
    final int tests = 200000;
    int twoHunderdIsAFactor = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
        if (random.nextInt() % 200 == 0) {
            twoHunderdIsAFactor += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Tests = " + tests + " Hits = " + twoHunderdIsAFactor + " Proportion = " + (tests / twoHunderdIsAFactor));
}
```

prints `Tests = 200000 Hits = 1012 Proportion = 197` - i.e. about `200` times for `200000` randoms.

Generating randoms in a specific range is dealt with in other answers.